# rolling back exec and sp_OA methods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, vb6, rollback

We have an instance where an old vb6 dll needs to be implemented and forces us to use sp_OACreate and sp_OAMethod. Given that the code will be inside a transaction, does anyone know whether or not the rollback will work for the code in that assembly? The assembly will access and make changes to the data.
Or will the sp_OAMethod call and the db code inside the assembly create it's own independent session outside of the transaction?

Thank you.

```
      begin tran
            declare @hr int
            declare @Object int
            declare @Return int
            declare @Output varchar(255)

            exec @hr= sp_OACreate 'DIssues32.Iclass',@object out
            IF @hr <> 0

            BEGIN

                EXEC sp_Getoaerrorinfo @object, @hr,@output out
                select @output

            END

            else
             begin


                exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @object,'Transfer', @Return , @LOCATION_NAME,
                    @TO_LOCATION_NAME, @QTY_REQUESTED,  @SYSUSER_ID, '', @CONNSTRING, True, '',  False, True

                IF @hr <> 0
                BEGIN
                    EXEC sp_Getoaerrorinfo @object, @hr,@output out
                    select @output
                    rollback
                END

                exec @hr= sp_OADestroy @object out

                print @return
             end
```

commit

Comment: Are you really saying it's not possible to manipulate data, inside the database, without using this VB6 (1998, cough cough) DLL and deprecated sp_OA methods? I think you should stop spending resources on worrying about rollback scenarios and instead invest in replacing this whole piece of code without something supported and scalable.

Comment: Aaron, that was not the question. Let me just say this once, if that was an option, I would not be asking the question. Please do not assume about resources, their availability, and investments. If I had concerns with this aspect I would be posting in the project management forums. This is a specific technical question.

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions. I asked a question, expressed an opinion, and gave a suggestion. Which is more than you've received from anyone else. "What type of drill should I use to clean my monitor?" is also a technical question, but the right solution is probably not going to be a direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `sp_bindsession` for the second connection (from VB6 component) to join the main lock space and share the transaction.

You can use `sp_getbindtoken` to get the token and pass it along the connection string but obviously the VB6 code will have to be tweaked to bind the session if token is found at the end of `@CONNSTRING`

Comment: wqw, Thank you for the information. I will run through it to test the code. Much appreciated.